# MemSQL very weird bug, characters missing

Tags: singlestore

I've used MemSQL for almost 3 years but I haven't had this issue before.
This is the query for creating table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table(
     filed1 VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
     field2 VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
     field3 VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY(filed1 , field2 , field3 ),
     KEY(field2 , field3 )
 );
```

With the next query, my field2 value is limited to 2 characters

> INSERT IGNORE INTO table (filed1 , field2 , field3 ) SELECT fieldX, "320", "11" FROM other_table WHERE fieldX IN ( "1"); notice one empty space before "1"

In this case, on my table it's saved 32 instead of 320. If I remove that empty space before "1", everything is fine. 
This is a pretty stupid one in my opinion. Also it's happening only on production environment, I can't reproduce it locally.
It is working in the same way with texts and not numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in versions of MemSQL prior to v6.5.  Once you update to v6.5 the issue should resolve.